# React Native Navigation GoBack isn't working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

im using react navigation 3 and also using

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(item.navigationPath)
```

to navigate through pages

the problem is when i click the button in navbar to go back it doesn't go back
i want it to go back 1 step but it do nothing

here is the back component

```
    class NavigationBack extends Component  {
    toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
  };
    render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          <Image
            source={require('./image/drawer.png')}
            style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Also when im in the Home->Category->Single-Category
and i press the hardware back button it take me to Home instead of Category

here is a link to snack 
https://snack.expo.io/@ov3rcontrol/navi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and made some modification. can you check this code ? is this what you need ?

```
/*Example of Navigation Drawer with Sectioned Menu*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  YellowBox,
  Dimensions,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

//Import required react-navigation component
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';

//Import all the screens
import Screen1 from './pages/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './pages/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './pages/Screen3';
import category from './pages/category';
import singleCategory from './pages/singleCategory';

//Import custom Drawer / sidebar
import SideMenu from './sidemenu';

//Navigation Drawer Structure for all screen
class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          {/*Donute Button Image */}
          <Image
            source={require('./image/drawer.png')}
            style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class NavigationBack extends Component  {
    toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
  };
    render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          <Image
            source={require('./image/drawer.png')}
            style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

//Stack Navigator for the First Option of Navigation Drawer
const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the First Option will be indexed here
  First: {
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 1',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

//Stack Navigator for the Second Option of Navigation Drawer
const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Second Option will be indexed here
  Second: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 2',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

//Stack Navigator for the Third Option of Navigation Drawer
const Screen3_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Third Option will be indexed here
  Third: {
    screen: Screen3,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 3',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});


const category_nav = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Third Option will be indexed here
  cat: {
    screen: category,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Makeup Artist',
      headerLeft: <NavigationBack navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

const single_category_nav = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Third Option will be indexed here
  single_cat: {
    screen: singleCategory,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Mahmoud Makup',
      headerLeft: <NavigationBack navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});
//Drawer Navigator for the Navigation Drawer / Sidebar
const Drawers = createStackNavigator({
  NavScreen1: { screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator },
    NavScreen2: { screen: Screen2_StackNavigator },
    NavScreen3: { screen: Screen3_StackNavigator },
    category: {screen: category_nav},
    single_category: {screen: single_category_nav}
},{
  headerMode: 'none'
})
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    drawerScreens: Drawers
  },
  {
    contentComponent: (props) => (
      <SideMenu {...props}/>
    ),
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - 120,
  }
);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  root: DrawerStack
},{
  headerMode: "none"
});

export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Comment: Yes it's working good but i wanted to make the burger menu in the navbar in category and single category pages go to the previous page just like the hardware button now do after your modification ty